# Virtual server on virtualmin keeps redirecting to wrong website

Tags: apache, nginx, virtualhost, webmin, virtualmin

I have created a virtual server say aaa.com but when I access the site (via editing my hosts file on Windows 7, cos I have a live aaa.com running on the Internet), it brings me to my other virtual server's site I have, like bbb.com

Why is that? I don't have any redirection running. Not in my script files (like html or php) and no redirection set under "Server Configurations" -> "Website Redirects" and none at "Services" -> "Click Configure Website" -> "Aliases and Redirects." The only script files I have are fresh new WordPress installation files (under home/aaa/public_html).

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Mullazman is right (thanks!). I have just had this problem after enabling the SSL on the domain A. Then, all the domains in the same installation were pointing to A.

I fixed it by editing the file located in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/A.conf` and changing the first line:

Wrong line -> `<VirtualHost A.B.C.D:80>`

Correct line -> `<VirtualHost *:80>`

Comment: Fixed it for me too

Comment: How do you change for 100+ domains?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. For anyone interested it's because I had  at the header of my sites-enables/aaa.com.conf which was picking up all requests and send them to the first host.

Change it to  and it started directing traffic to the correct virtual hosts.

It was triggered when I enabled SSL on aaa.com, it for some reason re-wrote the config file to use IP based filtering not domain name

Comment: How to handle it if i have 1000+ domains?

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete browser cache with CTRL+F5,
then try again. If that doesn't help, check virtualhost configuration files -maybe there lies the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found

I had the same problem ...

And I ended up with a lot of doubts ...
And I searched for a SOLUTION for this case, I hope to help ...

1 - Should the BIND have an external or internal IP in the domain? I use only one IP for all servers, and in BIND all domains are with external IP. (The question is whether it should be external or internal IP).

R = Yes, you must configure the internal IP in Virtualmin, prefer to edit the file. Only in localhost you should have 127.0.0.1

2 - Would NGINX have any configuration? How to remove IP and just put (listen *: 80) instead of (listen 288.218.198.981:80)

R = This configuration was changed but then I had problems with DNS and I returned to use the INTERNAL IP (not the localhost) ... Normally this IP starts as: 10.1xx.xx.xx

But which configuration would work in general?

Restart these steps ...
If you still have an error ...

Back up ... And in Virtualmin settings ...

> > Edit Virtual Server >> Activate Features >>
> >     Uncheck NGINX, BIND, NGINX SSL.
> >     He will ask for confirmation and click to confirm.

After this process is completed, return to the same option and reschedule ...
This will make it delete the old ones and put a new one.
(This works great for those who changed hosting and has old settings).

If you are importing a backup. Do not select the DNS and NGINX option ...
One tip is to create Virtual Server {your domain / site} First of all ...

And only then only import directories and databases ...

So you will not have problems with DNS and wrong redirects ...

---

Update

This also occurs when the SSL certificate is not issued correctly.

Folder permissions are incorrect.
Chmod 0755 folders
0644 Files

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION!!!

Cheap workaround let us say our domain is domain.xyz

Under the BindDNS Master Zone for domain.xyz create a cname record I believe it is listed in webmin as Name Alias and name it 000.domain.xyz

Under apache create a virtual server with the name 000.domain.xyz and make sure it has the same directory as domain.xyz

After this is done you are golden all your websites will come up as they should!

Is it proper well maybe not.

Does it work well like a charm of course otherwise I wouldn't be sharing for some reason the way the severs are listed it defaults to the first on the list well that'll fix that there should be a method of pinning the servers or doing something to prevent such a thing from happening what a pain in the rear I spent a full day dumbfounded thinking what in the world is going on I am losing my touch.

If this helps give a like if its wrong apologies all I know is that it works.

Read the thread.
Many folks claim this is an SSL thing.
Zero people have eluded to the true method of fixing it or the proper directions to do so or if they did I'm too blind to see it.
The guy below me commenting hrmmm... Yeah browser caches for my website didn't exist on my devices I tried them on to verify that was not the problem. But yes this is a typical problem with a lot of things indeed. It is the only reason I have several browsers on my PC actually for that reason. For a while there there were pages that chrome would function with that IE wouldn't or Firefox would best them both. Not to mention cache is always a pita its always usually one of my steps in troubleshooting any issues with web pages. I'll even try openDNS or other DNS servers.

But holy cats I can't believe how fast DNS just updates once you got things set it makes me wonder if there is a lot of fudge in propigation when you purchase hosting being "24 -48 hours" I think there is a lot of fudge in those numbers after my experiences trying to figure out what was causing the issue here. Some servers struggle yes but for the most part it was pretty instant for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it happened after creating SSL certificate, I forgot to do:

Edit Virtual Server -> Enable Apache SSL Website