# On Virtualmin redirect subdomain to a directory

Tags: wordpress, cookies, virtualmin

For my [website](https://phuketians.com) I created a subdomain called static.phuketians.com as they suggested for "cookie free domains" so it will improve my website load speed. This is a Wordpress site, so it was also suggested that this subdomain should point to `/wp-content`.

Any idea how I can manage this on Virtualmin?

Comment: Maybe it helps gather information... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48416386/virtual-server-on-virtualmin-keeps-redirecting-to-wrong-website/56589199#56589199

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you feel more familiar you can use redirection is a wordpress plugin